# JQuery -- Expected identifier for pseudo-class or pseudo-element but found '.'

Tags: jquery, debugging

How do I go about tracking this warning? I know *about* where to look, but what exactly am I looking for ... does this mean "classname" instead of ".classname" for some selector?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Needs [sample code](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a selector something like this:

```
$(":.blah")
```

or

```
$("div:.blah")
```

Namely, a period after the colon.

Or possibly two periods in a row.